# InflateException after locking and unlocking device

Tags: android

Okay, so I'm using `Android-X`.

I've Activity which opens up single fragment. That's it.
The only way I can reproduce this crash is by opening fragment and then locking device -> unlocking device and app is brought back and then this error happens.

```
2019-08-29 13:02:50.794 30359-30359/com.x E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.x, PID: 30359
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.x/com.x.Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3092)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5013)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4922)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6986)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: (activity as x…            .recyclerView must not be null
    at com.x.setObservables(XFragment.kt:116)
    at com.x.views.XFragment.onCreate(XFragment.kt:52)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2414)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:844)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1229)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1295)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2605)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2559)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.restoreChildFragmentState(Fragment.java:1535)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onCreate(Fragment.java:1507)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:203)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2414)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:844)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1129)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManagerImpl.java:3132)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:133)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:345)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:324)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
```

> Blockquote
>
> 2019-08-29 13:02:50.796 30359-30359/com.x E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:141)
>           at com.x.onCreate(ImageRecognitionActivity.kt:33)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7326)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7317)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5013)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4922)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6986)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)

Below is `ActivityX` layout if that helps

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_x" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/gray_dark"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="50dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:overScrollMode="never"

        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

As I understand, I try to reinfate activities view and that fails and later on in fragment I touch it (woopsy) and it gives NPE. Why does inflation of the view fail?

Comment: clearly say error in inflating your fragment

Comment: Please show us the activity code also. Not sure why you’re reinflating a view once it’s already inflated.